# Is my usage of “auch” correct?

Tags: sentence-structure, particle

To say:

> *I **also** come on the subway to school.*

would I write:

1. *Ich komme **auch** mit der U-Bahn zur Schule.*
2. *Ich **auch** komme mit der U-Bahn zur Schule.*

Or would it be something else?

Also, to say:

> *He is **also** fourteen.*

would I write:

1. *Er ist **auch** vierzehn.*
2. *Er **auch** ist vierzehn.*

Or would something else be correct?

Comment: Remember that "normal" german word order places the subject first, the verb second, and any other elements third. No matter which element begins a German declarative sentence (a statement), the verb is always the second element!

Comment: I hope you don't get arrested for coming on the subway... SCNR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second alternatives with *auch* between subject – here: pronouns – on the left and verb on the right are malformed. This particle, like others, comes after the verb, but since German syntax is more flexible than English you’ll occasionally see or hear it appear before the subject (and verb), usually for emphasis.

3. ***Auch ich** komme mit der U-Bahn zur Schule.*

This stresses the importance of the sentence subject (*ich*), probably in relation to previous statements by other people: *not only you/them, but me too*. In initial position it cannot be understood another way, whereas with standard medial position *auch* may apply to the subject:

1. ***Ich** komme **auch** mit der U-Bahn zur Schule.*

It could alter the meaning of the verb instead:

1. *Ich **komme auch** mit der U-Bahn zur Schule.*

   - *Ich **kann** mit der U-Bahn zur Schule **kommen**. (Ich nehme aber normalerweise den Bus)*

It could also apply to the first object¹ following it:

1. *Ich komme **auch mit der U-Bahn** zur Schule.*

   - *Ich komme **nicht nur mit der U-Bahn** zur Schule. (Ich muss außerdem den Bus nehmen.)*

The difference between those two nuances can safely be considered advanced nitpicking and doesn’t apply to the second example in the question. They share a possible repositioning which makes it otherwise unambiguous:

4. **Auch mit der U-Bahn** komme ich zur Schule.

If the particle should apply to the second object¹, *auch* would have to appear directly before it, regardless of its syntactic position:

- *Ich komme mit der U-Bahn (zum Training, aber) **auch zur Schule**.*
- ***Auch zur Schule** komme ich mit der U-Bahn.*

A short affirmative statement without a verb would have the particle follow the subject immediately:

- Alice: *Ich komme mit der U-Bahn zur Schule.*
  Bob: *Ich **auch**!* – ‘me too’, ‘so do I’.

---

¹ I’m using *object* in a very broad sense here, which includes prepositional phrases.

Answer (score 0):

Die erste Variante ist korrekt: Ich komme auch mit der U-Bahn zur Schule. Die Reihenfolge ist anders als in Englisch.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of " Ich auch komme..." just like "I also come ... " which means that, it is true however, it is not the best way to write that statement. That is why second sentence is better.